# Programmatically tap on FBSDKLikeControl

Tags: ios, facebook, uibutton, fbsdklikecontrol

I'm trying to simulate UI from Facebook SDK' button on my own `UIButton`. Actually I designed my button to use for liking Facebook page. For my button `.TouchUpInside` event I have written a function which makes in stack memory an instance of `FBSDKLikeContol` button and programatically simulates tapping on it:

```
let likeButton = FBSDKLikeControl(frame: CGRectZero)
likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/<some_id>"
likeButton.performSelectorOnMainThread("_handleLikeButtonTap:", withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
```

But I have not getting a fullscreen UIWebView for liking/unliking processes still. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would be **very** careful with what you are doing here - this might easily violate facebook tos. and it could stop working any second - as soon as the library developer changes its internal method architecture.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you. I have troubles with placing FBSDKLikeControl view in section header, so I decided to workaround with described subject rather than layout-ing native button to header. Seems I'll be do that soon. :)

Ok, let try to get rid from using selector signature. What about other method? `likeButton.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)`

Comment: In general I am surprised that acutally would work, I would have expected the like-Button is better secured. Without displaying ***the*** facebook like button you basically create a like without user interaction with the actual like button - would be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks. If you talking about ToS I will layout native button in native way definitely!

Comment: I am not saying that it certainly violates it, but I would be surprised if it is allowed in the ToS. Mainly you did not sound like you had though about that, therefore without any statement wether or not it actually is disallowed you have to do some research about it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#socialplugins 13.4, “Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins.” might as well be applicable here. // You really shouldn’t do it. The FB like button layout is familiar to the user and easily recognizable as that – best to leave it that way.